# Regex to extract a string after a date in Python

Tags: python, regex

Having these two types of string:

```
1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip

1635508858063-1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip
```

How can I get using regex the `111040` part of the string? It has always 6 digits.

My approach is: "*Take the 6 digit code after the YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_ part*", but any other approach is also welcome.

EDIT: The last part `_0CM.csv.zip` can be suceptible to change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you split on underscore and take the second-to-last element?

Comment: Do you need to use regex?

Comment: Isn't 111040 six digits?

Comment: It's 6, yes. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted a regex so here it is:

```regex
[0-9]{4}(?:_[0-9]{2}){5}_([0-9]{6})
```

- `[0-9]{4}`: match the first 4 digits of the year, this is our starting anchor
- `(?:_[0-9]{2}){5}`: after that, it follows with 5 two digit numbers (month, day, hour, minute, second) so we can just group them all and ignore them
- `([0-9]{6})`: get the 6 digits following the previous expression.

The desired number is in capture group 1 of this regex:

```py
import re
regex = '[0-9]{4}(?:_[0-9]{2}){5}_([0-9]{6})'
re.search(regex, '1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip').group(1)
```

Comment: My fault It's a 6 digit. Changing the last {5} to {6} works! Thank you"

Answer (score 1):

How about this pattern? Works if you match each line one-by-line:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_(\d{6})')
print(pattern.findall("1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return '' if an appropriate match isn't found.

```py
import re

strings = [
    "1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip",
    "1635508858063-1625212673449-2021_07_02_07_55_05_111040_0CM.csv.zip",
    'Test'
]

pattern = re.compile('_(\d{6})_')

digits = [pattern.search(string).group(1) if pattern.search(string) else '' for string in strings]

print(digits)
```